# "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later." error on magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am developing a website with magento and for somereason I am getting this error and email when I try to check out.

**Error :**

"There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later."

**Email**

```
Payment transaction failed.

Reason
Image is not a PNG

Checkout Type
onepage

Customer:
xxx

Items
Gift Certificate x 2 AUD 10
test product x 2 AUD 25
Gift Certificate x 1 AUD 10
test product x 2 AUD 25
test product x 1 AUD 25

Total:
AUD 155

Billing Address:
abhinab kayastha
ghj
gjhghj
g
jhgjhg, 7897
Togo
T: 234

Shipping Address:
abhinab kayastha
ghj
gjhghj
g
jhgjhg, 7897
Togo
T: 234

Shipping Method:
Free Shipping

Payment Method:
Check / Money order

Date & Time:
May 1, 2012 2:47:40 PM
```

Thanks
 Ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like there's an issue while creating a PDF file (probably the order PDF).

The error is thrown because at some point of the PDF creation Magento tries to include a `.png` file, which does *not* have the usual `PNG` signature in its first three bytes (like "real" `.png` files should).

See `lib/Zend/Pdf/Resource/Image/Png.php`.

Check your `var/log/exception.log` or set

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in your `index.php` to get an exception trace, which should help you to pin down the file causing the error.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply 

My log folder does not have exception.log file.  

I figured out the error is thrown from lib/Zend/Pdf/Resource/Image/Png.php.  but could not figure out from which file. 

Also 
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

doesnt show any error regarding images.

Any more help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

uploaded  valid png file under
Configuration -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design

and worked fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

This error occur due to low memory_limit, Increase memory_limit in your root or store .htaccess file add this below line in your .htaccess file.

```
## adjust memory limit
php_value memory_limit 256M
```